# Rviz not showing octomap from converting .dae mesh to .bt

Tags: ros, rviz, octomap, octovis

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to convert a static Collada (.dae) mesh into an `octomap_msgs::Octomap`. This [link](https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap/wiki/Importing-Data-into-OctoMap) was provided to me for assistance. Here are the steps I took:

1. Used `meshlab` to export mesh.dae into mesh.stl.
2. Used binvox to convert mesh.stl into mesh.binvoz. `./binvox /path/to/mesh/mesh.stl`
3. Used binvox2b to convert mesh.binvox into - mesh.binvox.bt. `./binvox2bt --mark-free /path/to/mesh/mesh.binvox`
4. Confirmed I could see Octomap using [Octovis](http://wiki.ros.org/octovis). `octovis /path/to/mesh/mesh.binvox.bt`

I then tried using the following ROS C++ code to display the Octomap in Rviz using octomap_rviz_plugins->OccupancyGrid.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <octomap_msgs/conversions.h>
#include <octomap_msgs/Octomap.h>
#include <octomap_msgs/GetOctomap.h>
#include <octomap_ros/conversions.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "octomap_read");
  ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
  spinner.start();
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  ros::Publisher octomap_publisher = nh.advertise<octomap_msgs::Octomap>("octomap",1);

  octomap::OcTree* octree = new octomap::OcTree("/path/to/mesh/mesh.binvox.bt");  

  octomap_msgs::Octomap bmap_msg;
  octomap_msgs::binaryMapToMsg(*octree, bmap_msg);  

  bmap_msg.header.seq = 0;
  bmap_msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
  bmap_msg.header.frame_id = "base_link"; 

  octomap_publisher.publish(bmap_msg); 

  while(octomap_publisher.getNumSubscribers() < 1)
  {
      ROS_WARN("Waiting for Subscribers");
      ros::Duration(1.0).sleep();
  }

  ros::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

However, when running the code, nothing happens and the status stays at `0 binary octomap messages received`. If I change the octomap file to an Octomap from [OctoMap 3D scan dataset](http://ais.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/projects/datasets/octomap/), it works just fine and shows up. I tried examining both `octomap_msgs::OctoMap` and they are nearly identical. The only difference is the Resolution and octomap.resolution and octomap.data.size().

What could be going wrong with my Octomap I am creating from a Collada mesh if I can see it using `Octovis` but not inside of Rviz?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267473/rviz-not-showing-octomap-from-converting-.dae-mesh-to-.bt/) by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 592 on 2017-07-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2017-07-26**:
You probably need to publish after waiting for a subscriber or make the publisher latched. I'd also recommend not exiting immediately after publishing. Just spin instead and ctrl-c it when you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem. The OctoMap was too large and was not being received when only publishing it once. I put the publish(octomap) inside of a rate function, and it showed up after a few seconds.

---

Originally posted by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) with karma: 592 on 2017-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0